# Folder is seen in CentOS but can't see the files created by windows hosts

Tags: centos, windows, samba

I am trying to connect windows 10 and CentOS 8 using Samba. These are the commands I have user

```
yum install samba samba-client samba-common -y
```

These are the configurations in /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = centos
security = user
map to guest = bad user
dns proxy = no
#============================ Share Definitions ==============================
[Anonymous]
path = /samba/anonymous
browsable =yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
```

This is the folder I have created to be shared

```
mkdir -p /samba/anonymous
```

Added the service to the firewall

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-service=samba
```

Changed the permission and context

```
chmod -R 0755 anonymous/
chown -R nobody:nobody anonymous/
chcon -t samba_share_t anonymous/
```

Now I am able to see the folder in both the windows and CentOS, but when I create anything in windows system I am not able to see it in the centOS shared folder. What went wrong here? I am new to this so I have no clue other than this.

Comment: Have you tested by mounting on CentOS and creating a file? So that you can see if it is network/windows problem or linux problem.

Comment: How to mount? I think samba used to work without any of that

Comment: I mean can you create a file when you login from the same machine where the share resides?

Comment: Yes I can create a file in CentOS in the same folder

Comment: You created it over samba?   Then it may be a windows problem.

Comment: `mount.cifs` is how you mount or `mount -t cifs what where`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by creating `/home/anonymous` directory. I changed the path option in `smb.conf` to point to this directory, and the problem was solved